# Winter18-Event fields are not displaying in activity timeline (compact layout)

Tags: event, winter18

Event fields are not displaying in activity timeline(Compact Layout)  after lead/opportunity page refresh.
It will appear once i create new Event in Lead/Opportunity.
It was working fine before w18 release.